# Helm Kubernetes connect to mysql chart from my nodejs chart inside same cluster

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS application using helm chart inside an AKS cluster and within the same cluster, I want to install `MYSQL` helm chart and connect it from my `NodeJS` application.

Here's what I have done so far:

1): First, I have installed the `mysql` chart on my cluster using the command below:

```
helm install --name mysql --set mysqlRootPassword=rootpassword,mysqlUser=mysql,mysqlPassword=my-password,mysqlDatabase=mydatabase,persistence.existingClaim=mysql-pvc stable/mysql
```

2): After that, I have installed my `nodejs` application chart and here how I'm using the `mysql` chart in my application:

```
  connections: {
    mysqlDB: {
        adapter: 'mysqlAdapt',
        host: process.env.default.svc.cluster.local,
        database: 'mydatabase',
        user:'root',
        password:'my-password',
        port: 3306,
        supportBigNumbers:true, //true/false
        debug:['ComQueryPacket'], //false or array of node-mysql debug options
        trace:true //true/false
    } 
  }
};
```

but when I run my application service from kubernetes cluster and my pod becomes 'CrashLoopBackOff` and return the error below:

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

I'm new to helm and kubernetes, how can I connect to `MySQL` helm chart from my `nodejs application`? and I'm using the right approach to use a SQL database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What steps have you already taken to debug the problem?  (For example, what does that `connections` object actually contain?)

Comment: I'm using the `waterline.js ORM for NodeJS` to work with `mysql` database and when I got the logs by running `kubectl logs POD -p` then it shows the error above which says `Could not connect to MySQL`.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `process.env.default.svc.cluster.local` with mysql Pod's IP address?

Comment: Why you use 127.0.0.1:3306? If the mysql works well, then you try to use the address 0.0.0.0:3306.